# Why Doesn't This Child CSS Selector Work?

Tags: css

According to everything I read, the code below should render a single item unordered list with a red border.  Shouldn't it?

But it doesn't, so I'm obviously missing something very important about css selectors. Can anyone set me straight?

```css
ul.circle {
  margin: 1em 0 0 0 0;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  list-style-type: circle;
}

ul.circle > li {
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<ul class='circle'>
  <li>
    XXXXXXXXXXX
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: it's working fine

Comment: ... in the snipped is working fine...

Comment: I'm too embarrassed to tell you that I should have quadruple checked the spelling in the link to the css file.  So I won't.  But I will say reply is correct, appreciated and embarrassing.  (I'd mark it correct if you got any credit for that ... and I can figure out if that's possible. If not, I'll try to delete it ... grin ... or I guess live in infamy.  This is a wonderful site for learners.